# JSF f:ajax listener call bean method only if inputtext is not empty

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to call `f:ajax` listener when event `blur` is invoked, but only if the inputtest field value is not empty?

when the inputtext is blured i'm calling a method inside my managed bean, which returns all of the other form fields. the problem is when i blur an emtpy field, beacuse it's a required field i get a validation message, but in this case i don't want it to call the managed bean method, only if there a value inside of it.

How can this ve done?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: You can use JavaScript code to validate this in the `onevent` tag attribute.

Comment: Your question/problem is hard to understand. The ajax listener method is already not invoked when a validation error occurs. What exactly is your concrete problem? That the validation error is been shown on blur of an empty field?

Comment: @BalusC: yes, incase of onbluring an empty field i don't want any action to be taken..

Answer (score 0):

Use `event="change"` instead of `event="blur"` or just remove the `event` attribute altogether, it defaults to `change` already. This way the field will only be submitted (and validated) when it has really changed and thus not already when the enduser just leaves the field.

Comment: didn't had the chance to test it yet, will try it soon, thank's.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay.. I still get the UIinput.REQUIRED validation error message. I want the action to be conditinially performed - only if the input is not empy to perform the action.. Is it possible in another way? thank's.